# Copy content from <td> into a text box using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

With the code below, I don't seem to be able to just set the textbox to the value of an TD element. What I need to achieve is to populate **Enter Refund Amount** box with the already present value of **Grand Total field** above. Nothing else is needed except copying the content from one element to the other.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var src = document.getElementById("grand_total").innerHTML;
    dst = document.getElementById("refund_amount").innerHTML;
    src.addEventListener('#refund_amount', function() {
        dst = src;
    });
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `#refund_amount` isn't a valid event name. Given the context of the code and your goal I would assume that should be `click` instead. You also need to bind the event handler on the Element reference, not the a string variable containing its `innerHTML` value. In addition, to set the value of an `input` element you need to use the `value` property of the Element directly. Try this:

```js
var src = document.getElementById("grand_total");
var dst = document.getElementById("refund_amount");

src.addEventListener('click', function() {
  dst.value = src.textContent;
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Grand total:</td>
      <td id="grand_total">26.58</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Refund amount:</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="refund_amount" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the efforts, but this doesn't seem to work. The question is edited to give your more details on the goal. Please check.

Comment: Apologies, it works when I click the grand total. What I want is Enter Refund Amount should be set with grandtotal once the page loads.

Comment: *when page loads* - then just use `dst.value = src.textContent;` outside the event handler (inside your original window.onload)

Comment: @Rory, could you please kindly look at my post here on how to get elements by class name. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71830436/iterate-through-textarea-fields-under-a-specific-element-and-strip-emojis-from-t. Please suggest some possible solutions.