# Iterate through textarea fields under a specific class to strip emojis from a textarea field whose name has Gift Message as substring

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend, web-deployment

I'm looking only for a pure JavaScript solution to the problem I'm trying to fix with the code and the logic below. I'm stuck being unable to get the value of the textarea field whose name contains Gift Message as a substring of its name. Could you please help fix this?

The HTML is as follows:

```
<span class="bold_option_element">
    <textarea name="properties[Enter Gift Message Below. NO EMOJIS PLEASE. Remember to sign your name! ]" class="ta_570739_262324" maxlength="1000">
    </textarea>
  <textarea name="properties[Test Gift ]" class="ta_570739_262324" maxlength="1000">
    </textarea>
</span>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    {%- comment -%}
        This block of code checks if emojis are present in gift message, on keyup event
        Logic:
        1. Get value of textarea field for gift message.
        2. Get the textarea "bold_option_element" fields whose name has "GiftMessage" after stripping all blanks.
        3. Return false if emojis are present.
        Refer: https://melvingeorge.me/blog/check-if-string-contain-emojis-javascript for emoji validation
    {%- endcomment -%}
    window.onkeyup = function(e) {
        // Get gift message string.
        giftMessage = "Hello  ";
        let textAreaElements = document.getElementsByClassName('bold_option_element');
        console.log(textAreaElements);
        const regexExp = /(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])/gi;
        if (regexExp.test(giftMessage)) {
            alert("No EMOJIs are allowed in the Gift Message. EMOJIs have been deleted in the Gift Messsage. Edit your Gift Message and 'Add to Cart'");
            return false;
        }
        return true;    
    };
</script>
```

Link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pramodraam/vhqyj15m/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your selector outside of the `keyup` handler.
Use `addEventListener` rather than `onkeyup`

The selector for your text areas with `Gift Message` in the `name` attribute is:

`".bold_option_element > textarea[name*='Gift Message']"`

I used it in `.querySelectorAll()` as you'll see below.

Finally, since this is async, returning a value from an event listener is a noop. You'll need to use that Boolean within the handler itself as demonstrated below.

Code is commented.

```js
// Get only the textareas with "Gift Message" in name attribute
let textAreaElements = document.querySelectorAll(".bold_option_element > textarea[name*='Gift Message']");

// Add event listener to each textarea with "Gift Message" in name attribute
textAreaElements.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('keyup', checkForEmoji);

});
// keyup event handler to check for emoji
function checkForEmoji(e) {
  // Stores result of async Operation
  let result = true;

  const regexExp = /(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])/gi;
  if (regexExp.test(e.target.value)) {
    alert("No EMOJIs are allowed in the Gift Message. EMOJIs have been deleted in the Gift Messsage. Edit your Gift Message and 'Add to Cart'");

    // EDIT: Added code to remove emoji
    e.target.value = e.target.value.replaceAll(regexExp, '');

    result = false;
  }
  // Do something with result here
  console.log(result);
};
```

```html
<span class="bold_option_element">
  <textarea name="properties[Enter Gift Message Below. NO EMOJIS PLEASE. Remember to sign your name! ]" class="ta_570739_262324" maxlength="1000"></textarea>
  <textarea name="properties[Test Gift ]" class="ta_570739_262324" maxlength="1000"></textarea>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Randy. How to blank out all emojis once the alert is displayed and closed?

Comment: Your solution works fine when running code snippet. When I applied it in the product page of our Shopify site, it doesn't seem to work. You can check it yourself by visiting the product page on this preview theme https://g2vbclq0dt1xmuy9-458195004.shopifypreview.com

Comment: To make this work in your theme, try adding `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()` as the first two lines of the event handler. Other event handlers are preventing your code from working using this same technique, so it may not work. As for removing the emoji, I'll modify the snippet when I get a moment.

Comment: I've added the code that will remove the emoji from the input

Comment: Added those two lines. It still didn't work on keyup after entering an emoji in the box. What else can I try?

Comment: In that case, you'll have to fall back to using the `.onkeyup` property on the element. Something like this will work: `document.querySelector('textarea[name*="Gift Message"]').onkeyup = (e)=>{e.stopPropagation; e.preventDefault(); /* Do stuff here */ }`

Comment: Okay, thanks, will try it out and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks Randy, it worked.  I would request you to just let me know how to keep the first accordion in the page open by default with CSS or JavaScript if CSS can't help? Please visit a product page to see the accordions Description, Impact and Additional info. I need to keep Description open by default. https://2gu1r58srf2bq74n-458195004.shopifypreview.com

Comment: That is a different, unrelated question. Please create a new question to ask for help with this. It is frowned upon to ask multiple questions in comments on SO. Thanks.

Comment: Sure Randy. I obey your advices.

Comment: Randy, I posted that question. Please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71895900/first-accordion-to-be-made-open-by-default-either-by-javascript-or-css

Comment: Randy, I've a request for you. Could you please have a look at this post to see if you can suggest some solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71910147/close-previously-opened-accordion-with-pure-javascript?noredirect=1#comment127070019_71910147

Comment: Randy, could you please have a look at the post on trouble reading active element? Link to it is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73364211/hide-open-active-accordion-when-another-accordion-is-clicked