# First accordion to be made open by default either by JavaScript or CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web, frontend

I got 3 accordions in a Shopify product page out of which I intend to keep the first one expanded by default on page load. Once the page loaded, clicking other accordions should close all previously opened ones. I want to do it only with pure JavaScript(no libraries like jQuery) or CSS. My code below just ensures the first accordion is shown expanded. Could you please help correct my code after having a look at the accordions in the page https://wv3yau73hiyf9fhv-458195004.shopifypreview.com?

```
 window.onload = function() {
  var accItem = document.getElementsByClassName('accordion__item');
  // Keep the first accordion open by default.
  for (i = 0; i < accItem.length; i++) {
    console.log("Within first for loop");
    accItem[0].click();
    accItem[i].addEventListener('click', toggleItem, false);
  }
  function toggleItem() {
    var itemClass = this.parentNode.className;
    for (i = 0; i < accItem.length; i++) {
      console.log("Within second for loop");
      accItem[i].className = 'accordion__item close';
    }
    if (itemClass == 'accordion__item close') {
        this.parentNode.className = 'accordion__item open';
    }
  }    
 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the solution is below:

```
  // Keep the first accordion open by default.
  let allAccordions = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion__item");
  if (allAccordions.length > 0) {
    allAccordions[0].querySelector("input[type=radio]").checked = true;
  }
  // Capture click event for the accordions
  allAccordions.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', function() {
      let radioBtn = this.querySelector("input[type=radio]");
      let clickedRadioName = radioBtn.getAttribute("name");

      allAccordions.forEach(element => {
        let elementRadioBtn = element.querySelector("input[type=radio]");
        let elementRadioName = elementRadioBtn.getAttribute("name");
        if ((elementRadioName != clickedRadioName) && elementRadioBtn.checked) {
          element.querySelector("input[type=radio]").checked = false;
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution, had me stumped. I didn't think about checking the `input[type=radio]`, but good work ... upvoted!

Comment: Welcome Paul, I'm grateful to you for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 2):

Using the browser's console on the page, I used the following to open the first accordion:

```
let allAccordions = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion__item");
allAccordions[0].click();
```

Yes, a loop is possible too:

```
for (var i = 0; i < allAccordions.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
          allAccordions[i].click();
          break; // only the first, can stop looping.
    }
}
```

Comment: Paul, can we use some forloop to avoid hardcoding like allAccordions[0] if you think it better?

Comment: Yes, a loop is possible too, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there no other way than using this conventional forloop? I was expecting something like .foreach()

Comment: Well, cannot break from a `forEach` loop. However, [other loops](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/foreach-break) are possible.

Comment: Paul, can you add a line of code to ensure the previously opened accordion gets closed when another accordion is clicked. Please visit a product page here https://gjw3fmvmdrf6ycne-458195004.shopifypreview.com

Comment: I'll take a look, but it will likely be much later today. I don't think that will be a simple one line of code, though, as the handling has to work with whether the `label.collapse` CSS has the `display` set when it shows the `±` toggle.

Comment: Okay Paul, please take your time to help me.

Comment: The accordion being used is one of the blocks offered by Booster theme that I'm customizing for a Shopify store. I'm just adding that block to the product page. No library did I install in the project for it.

Comment: Paul, can't we apply the same logic to accordion to close it when we click the other one?

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but it didn't seem to work so easily that way. I'll have to see what boost might offer and try again later.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Paul. The theme name is Booster and it is a third party Shopify theme.

Comment: T, could you please have a look at the post on trouble reading active element? Link to it is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73364211/hide-open-active-accordion-when-another-accordion-is-clicked